# Pine script hline function

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

i am trying some simple for loop using hline but i get error as below:

Cannot call 'hline' with 'price'=series[integer]. The argument should be of type: input float

Script:-

```
for s = 0 to 2
    hline(425 + s, title = "top line", color=color.green, linestyle=hline.style_solid, linewidth=2)

plot(close)
```

Can someone please help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `hline` in local scope.

Use `line.new()` instead.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

if barstate.islast
    for s = 0 to 2
        line.new(bar_index, 425 + s, bar_index + 1, 425 + s, extend=extend.both)
```

[image]

Comment: That worked like a charm, thank you so much Vitruvius. Though i am trying further for adding ladel above line on right side of chart to show which day its from but not able to do so.. if you can pls suggest what i am doing wrong, it will be very helpful

            _gettime = time[425+s]
            _getdayofmonth = dayofmonth(_gettime)
            _l := label.new( bar_index[s], 425+s, tostring(_getdayofmonth) ,xloc = xloc.bar_index, yloc = yloc.abovebar )
            label.delete(_l[1])

Comment: I did try using str.format("{0,date,d-M-YYYY}", _gettime) and it did convert time to format i need but then still not what i need.. i want it to be on right side of chart and just above the line i draw using line.new()

Comment: Please ask another question for that. And consider accepting my post as an answer if it solved your original problem.

Comment: Sure will do, thanks much.